# Why is my 'magento' directory missing from lib/internal?

Tags: magento2, installation, directory

Apologies if this is a duplicate, not appropriate, etc. I have just installed Magento 2.0.0 and a lot of the documentation I am reading/watching mentions a 'magento' directory in lib/internal, but I my install does not seem to have this folder. Any ideas on why this might be would be amazing helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you did the setup using composer.

In a composer installation of magento2 there is no lib/internal/Magento folder instead it is in the vendor folder, "vendor/magento/framework" to be precise.

But if you see the magento2 repository on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework) you should see the "lib/internal/Magento" folder.

Comment: It is not absolutely correct, if you are using Magento Commerce, even you download the zip and install via web interface, there is also no lib/internal/Magento, and things are inside vendor/magento. But if you are using Magento Open source , then you are correct